# cd tray not working properly

Tags: cd-drive

My cd tray of T400 sometimes pops it out by itself. But when I want to eject it by pushing its button, it doesn't respond. How can I fix the problem? Thanks. ubuntu 12.04

Here are some commands.

```
$ eject -v
eject: using default device `cdrom'
eject: device name is `cdrom'
eject: expanded name is `/dev/cdrom'
eject: `/dev/cdrom' is a link to `/dev/sr0'
eject: `/dev/sr0' is not mounted
eject: `/dev/sr0' is not a mount point
eject: `/dev/sr0' is not a multipartition device
eject: trying to eject `/dev/sr0' using CD-ROM eject command
eject: CD-ROM eject command succeeded

$ sudo umount /dev/cdrom
umount: /dev/cdrom: not mounted

$ sudo eject /dev/cdrom -v
eject: device name is `/dev/cdrom'
eject: expanded name is `/dev/cdrom'
eject: `/dev/cdrom' is a link to `/dev/sr0'
eject: `/dev/sr0' is not mounted
eject: `/dev/sr0' is not a mount point
eject: `/dev/sr0' is not a multipartition device
eject: trying to eject `/dev/sr0' using CD-ROM eject command
eject: CD-ROM eject command succeeded
```

Information about it

```
  *-cdrom
       description: DVD-RAM writer
       product: DVDRAM GSA-U20N
       vendor: HL-DT-ST
       physical id: 1
       bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
       logical name: /dev/cdrom
       logical name: /dev/cdrw
       logical name: /dev/dvd
       logical name: /dev/dvdrw
       logical name: /dev/sr0
       version: HX12
       capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
       configuration: ansiversion=5 status=open
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you think it is not a hardware problem?

Comment: I don't know. I don't think it is or not.

Answer (score 0):

My problem is similar in Ubuntu 14.04. 
If I use "eject" to remove a data cd and then close the empty tray, the button on the tray stops working. The command
"sudo eject -v"
fails to open the tray.
I do not believe it is a hardware fault as after a restart the button works again.